# Change date format with csh under Windows 10

Tags: date, sed, csh, self-modifying

I have a command file that looks like this:

```
date /t > stu.txt
sed -e 's/\//-/g' stu.txt | c:\Bin\MKS\cut -c5-14 >stu2.txt
```

`stu2.txt` contains `03-08-2017`.

I want to change that to `2017-03-08` and then store in a variable named
`mydate` so that later, I can use that as part of a file name.

I have tried many things but no luck - suggestions here haven't worked.

This is a command file that runs on Windows 10, but that shouldn't matter if my code is right. I run Csh on my Windows machine (MKS Toolkit).

Comment: Does `date +%Y-%m-%d` work on that Win/csh combination?

Comment: No - not so worried about date conversion but mostly how to store date from a file into a variable

Comment: OK, I don't understand. *sh does not have something like a date _object_. The best you can do is `VARIABLE_NAME=\`cat filename.txt\``.